# Blocking a USB Device using SetupDiCallClassInstaller takes long time

Tags: winapi, usb, msdn

I created an application to block USB devices using SetupDiCallClassInstaller function. 

But in some OS, the blocking process takes only 1 or 2 secs to block the inserted device. Here blocking refers to disabling the USB devices.

In some OS, it takes 30 secs to 2 minutes to block a USB Devices.

Here I shared some part of my code :

```
    SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS spPropChangeParams;
    spPropChangeParams.StateChange = DICS_DISABLE;
    spPropChangeParams.ClassInstallHeader.cbSize = sizeof(SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER);
    spPropChangeParams.ClassInstallHeader.InstallFunction = DIF_PROPERTYCHANGE ;
    spPropChangeParams.Scope = DICS_FLAG_GLOBAL ;
    spPropChangeParams.HwProfile = 0; // current hardware profile

    printf("Time Before Blocking Device : %s\n",GetCurrTime());

    if(SetupDiSetClassInstallParams(m_hDevInfo, &m_DeviceInfoData,(SP_CLASSINSTALL_HEADER*)&spPropChangeParams, sizeof(SP_PROPCHANGE_PARAMS))== FALSE )
    {
        printf("Not able to manage the status of the device.SetupDiSetClassInstallParams Failed at ErrorCode - %ld\n",GetLastError());
    }

    else if(!SetupDiCallClassInstaller(DIF_PROPERTYCHANGE,m_hDevInfo, &m_DeviceInfoData))
    {
        DWORD error = GetLastError();
        printf("Not able to manage the status of the device.SetupDiCallClassInstaller API Failed at Errorcode - %ld\n",error);
        {
            if(error == 13)
            {
                for(int i=0;i< RETRY_TIME ;i++)
                {
                    if(SetupDiCallClassInstaller(DIF_PROPERTYCHANGE,m_hDevInfo, &m_DeviceInfoData))
                    {
                        printf("retry succeeded for disabling device\n");
                        break;
                    }
                    printf("retry failed for disabling device\n");  
                    Sleep(20);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Time After Blocking Device : %s\n",GetCurrTime());
```

> OUTPUT is:
>
> Time Before Blocking Device : 18:57:48
>   Time After Blocking Device : 18:59:18
>
> ---
>
> Here, it takes 1.30 minutes to block the device.

**Note :** Once the device is blocked(i.e.)disabled. Then I go to Device Manager and I enable the Device which is disabled. Then again it takes long time to block that devices.


Kindly revert back for any clarifications.

Thanks and Regards,

AK

Answer (score 1):

Does Device Manager need such a long time to disable the device too? What kind of USB devices have such problems?

The term "disabling a device" is not IMO precise. When you instruct the system to disable certain device, the device is kindly asked whether it is possible to disable it (and whether it allows such an action). Only if the device agrees to be disabled, the system actually disables it.

If you have problems with specific devices, there may be a bug in their drivers. I have a similar experience with my Samsung external SSD drive. Sometimes, when it is idle for a long time and probably enters a sleep state, it is then quite problematic either to power it up again, or even to disable it. The attempt to disable it actually succeeds but takes a long time (several minutes). When I enable the device again, it starts working perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You are saying that only some devices have that issue... right!